# Парсинг с сайта в потоке

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер.

В потоке используется `WebClient`, на каждый поток выдается своя группа ссылок, но почему то не всегда получает html код страницы, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка.

Сорри за длинный код, сократил бы, да не знаю в чем трабла.

Спасибо.

```
private void DoWork1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        var worker1 = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        var tuple = (Tuple<List<string>, int, ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>>)e.Argument;

        string tmpStrToList = "";

        foreach (string val in tuple.Item1)
        {
            if (val != "")
            {
                List<string> arrRes = new List<string>();

                string html = "";

                try
                {
                    var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    html = webClient.DownloadString(val.ToString().Trim());

                    Thread.Sleep(0);

                    //Составляем регулярку для html кода
                    string pattern = @"<td>(.*)</td>";
                    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
                    Match match = reg.Match(html);

                    lock (sync1)
                    {
                        while (match.Success)
                        {
                            arrRes.Add(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
                            match = match.NextMatch();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    while (html == "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                            html = webClient.DownloadString(val.ToString().Trim());
                        }    
                        catch     
                        {

                        } 
                    }

                    //Составляем регулярку для html кода
                    string pattern = @"<td>(.*)</td>";
                    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
                    Match match = reg.Match(html);

                    Thread.Sleep(0);

                    while (match.Success)  
                    {   
                        arrRes.Add(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim()); 
                        match = match.NextMatch();
                    }
                }
            }

        tuple.Item3.TryAdd(tuple.Item2, tmpStrToList.Trim());

        count_for++;

        tmpStrToList = "";
    }
```

Comment: В NN-цатый раз: 1) ведите логи, в ключевых точках пишите в них информацию 2) воспользуйтесь отладчиком (правда, в многопоточном приложении это сложней, но можно). Разбираться с вашим кодом никому не интересно, поэтому в любом случае сужайте код до минимального. И сформулируёте вопрос более конкретно, потому что из вот этого: "почему то рандомная часть контента не парсится" вообще мало что можно понять. А потом уже откуда-то возникает "не всегда получает html"...

Comment: Проблема в том что:

var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
html = webClient.DownloadString(val.ToString().Trim());

не всегда получает html, уже и условие try catch для него создал, в блоке catch уже цикл while если try не получило html, который должен выполняться пока не получит html. Но один фиг не пашет.

while (html == "")
{
  try
  {
    var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    html = webClient.DownloadString(val.ToString().Trim());

  }    
  catch     
  {
  }

Comment: А почему вдруг `catch { }`? Вы подавляете все ошибки, а потом гадаете, где же ошибка. Не ленитесь, обработайте ошибки правильно. Хотя бы залогируйте, что происходит.

Comment: В логах ничего интересного, стандартные исключения:

Запрос был прерван: Соединение было неожиданно закрыто.
или
Время ожидания операции истекло.

Я вот сомневаюсь в 

while (html == "") { try { var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient(); webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; html = webClient.DownloadString(val.ToString().Trim());

}
catch
{ }
}
правильно ли составлен цикл?

Comment: @z668: (1) `try { ... } catch {}` — никогда не правильно. Вы должны ловить лишь те исключения, которые ожидаете (и возможно не на этом уровне). (2) может, вы чересчур часто стучитесь на сервер, и он даёт отлуп? правильный ответ от сервера — добрая воля сервера.

Comment: >не всегда получает html

@z668, вообще результат веб-запроса надо смотреть по HTTP-заголовкам, а не по "получили/не получили html".

Comment: @klopp: о, в тред пришёл сетевой программист, +1.

Comment: @VladD  В том то и дело что сервак дохлый (идет слишком большая нагрузка на бд сервера в следствии неграмотного php кода) и он так и будет давать "отлуп", именно для этого я и сделал while (html == "").
Я вот еще что подумал - а какое ограничение на максимальной количество потоков BackgroundWorker? Может я потоков просто слишком много ставлю.

Comment: @z688: ну, сервер и так дохлый, а вы его ещё насилуете в цикле :-)

Будьте добрее к серверу: выясните ошибку, и если она лежит на стороне сервера, выдержите таймаут (проинформировав пользователя), и попытайтесь снова. Если вы заDOSите сервер, пользы ни вам, ни серверу не будет.

Comment: BTW, в MSDN написано:


A WebClient instance does not send optional HTTP headers by default. If your request requires an optional header, you must add the header to the Headers collection. For example, to retain queries in the response, you must add a user-agent header. Also, servers may return 500 (Internal Server Error) if the user agent header is missing.


И чтобы не насиловать сервер хорошо бы обрабатывать Last-Modified (If-Modified-Since, соответственно, на стороне клиента). Хотя, это уже больше от сервера зависит.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jHV868Vi

Раскопал свой код чёрт знает какой давности, тоже в `_beginthread()` работал. Безо всяких C# :) Может поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем пришлось колхозить:

```
string[] res;

try
 {

 HttpWebRequest reqGET = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(val.ToString().Trim());
 reqGET.ContinueTimeout = 100;
 reqGET.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 reqGET.Method = @"GET";
 reqGET.ContentType = @"text/html; charset=utf-8";
 reqGET.Referer = @"http://yandex.ru";
 reqGET.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
 reqGET.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0";
 reqGET.KeepAlive = true;
 System.Net.WebResponse resp = reqGET.GetResponse();
 System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
 System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
 html = sr.ReadToEnd();
 resp.Close();
 stream.Close();

 res = html.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (res[res.Length - 1].ToString().Trim() != "html>")
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```